# How to handle multiple bound pairs for one variable in pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

Is it possible to define multiple bound pairs for a pyomo variable?

I tried to enter the bounds this way:

`model.variable = Var(..., bounds = [(0,0.1),(0.2,1)]` (So the variable can only take values between 0 and 0.1 and between 0.2 and 1) But this gives a type error for unknown type: tuple

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what you are trying to do here is a bit more complicated and cannot be done with "regions" or such within a bound.  You'll need to formulate a more complicated model with binary variables that indicate which region you are in and a set of corresponding constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The below is linear and can be used for an arbitrary number of intervals.  You'll need an indicator variable to indicate which range and a big-M value to set up the constraints (shown.)

*Side note*:  If your intervals are evenly spaced (as might be indicated by your question), then there are easier solutions to be had by using an integer variable and multiplying by a step-size with offset or such which will reduce the number of variables.  Not consequential unless you have *many* intervals.

##### Code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from itertools import chain

# some non-overlapping ranges...
ranges = [(0.0, 0.2), (0.4, 3.5), (4.5, 72.1)]

big_M = max(chain(*ranges))

# make model

m = pyo.ConcreteModel('range_selector')

# SETS
m.I = pyo.Set(initialize=range(len(ranges)))


# VARS
m.x = pyo.Var()  # the variable of interest
m.r = pyo.Var(m.I, domain=pyo.Binary)

# CONTSTRAINTS

# must be in one (and only one) range
m.one_range = pyo.Constraint(expr=sum(m.r[i] for i in m.I) == 1)

@m.Constraint(m.I)
def lower_bound(m, i):
    """enforce the lower bound if this range is selected"""
    return m.x >= m.r[i] * ranges[i][0]


@m.Constraint(m.I)
def upper_bound(m, i):
    """enforce the upper bound if this range is selected, else arbitrarily large"""
    return m.x <= ranges[i][1] + (1-m.r[i]) * big_M 

# some arbitrary constraint to force a range
m.t = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.x >= 2.0)

# OBJ
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=m.x)  # minimize x

# check it...
# m.pprint()

# SOLVE
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
res = solver.solve(m)
print(res)
m.r.display()
m.obj.display()
```

##### Output:

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 2.0
  Upper bound: 2.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 5
  Number of variables: 4
  Number of binary variables: 3
  Number of integer variables: 3
  Number of nonzeros: 1
  Sense: minimize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  User time: -1.0
  System time: 0.0
  Wallclock time: 0.01
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
    Black box: 
      Number of iterations: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.024441957473754883
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

r : Size=3, Index=I
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      0 :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
      1 :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
      2 :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
    Key  : Active : Value
    None :   True :   2.0
```

Comment: In the general definition shoulnd't you have your lower bound to be `return m.x >= m.r[i] * ranges[i][0] + (1-m.r[i]) * min(chain(*ranges))`, to be symmetrical to your upper bound?

Comment: @Learningisamess Sure.  I made the (convenient) assumption that the lowest region was bound at 0, which aligns with the OP’s question.  If any of the regions spanned negative values, then you are exactly right.

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation, the bound attribute cannot support union of two disjoint intervals, see https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Variables.html (it only accepts a single interval).

You need to define this as an additional constraint:

```
model.variable = Var(..., bounds = (0,1))
model.variable_constraint =  Constraint(rule=lambda model: model.variable <0.1 or model.variable > 0.2)
```

Edit:
As pointed out my constraint here-above is not legal. Here is a workaround, it uses two variables, one for each of your intervals, and a flag (binary variable) to switch between the two:

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.left_domain_x = pyo.Var(within=pyo.Reals, bounds=(0, 0.1))
model.right_domain_x = pyo.Var(within=pyo.Reals, bounds=(0.2, 1))
model.domain_flag = pyo.Var(within=pyo.Binary)

model.x = model.domain_flag * model.left_domain_x + (1-model.domain_flag)*model.right_domain_x

model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr = -model.x**2)

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('/opt/homebrew/bin/ipopt')
solution = opt.solve(model)
model.display()
```

Should be generalizable to the union of more intervals.

Second edit: continuing on the generalizability, here is how it can work with a larger number of intervals, using a vector of flags contrained to unit norm.

```py
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

bounds = np.linspace(0,1, 20).reshape(-1,2).tolist()

model.I = pyo.Set(initialize=list(range(len(bounds))))
model.__inner_x_flags = pyo.Var(model.I, domain=pyo.Binary)
model.__inner_x = pyo.Var(model.I, domain=pyo.Reals, bounds=bounds)

model.__inner_x_constraint = pyo.Constraint(rule=lambda model : sum(model.__inner_x_flags[i] for i in model.I)==1)

# the "facade" bounded variable
model.x = sum( model.__inner_x[i]* model.__inner_x_flags[i] for i in model.I)

model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr = -model.x**2)
opt = pyo.SolverFactory('/opt/homebrew/bin/ipopt')
opt.options['tol'] = 1e-11
solution = opt.solve(model)
model.display()
-np.log10(abs(pyo.value(model.x)))
```

Comment: That's not a legal constraint...

Comment: I tried your solution with an additional constraint but I got the following pyomo exception: Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (variable  <  0.1) to bool.
This error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable Param in a
Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking container
membership or equality.

Comment: Indeed my proposed solution did not work (I could not test it when I typed it, my bad). Check my edit, I am proposing a new (and tested) solution.

Comment: The updated solution is unnecessarily non-linear.

Comment: Do you mean I could use `n-1` flags? yeah indeed, I went for shorter syntax as my post is long enough. Feel free to contribute beyond your nay chat

Comment: No, I mean that you are multiplying variables together => nonlinear problem, which has many unnecessary complications.  This can be done w/ big-M constraint...stby